# Recursively type Declared Functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell

For a miniature project to learn Haskell, I have decided I am going to make a Deterministic Finite State machine program.

I thought I had a really clever way of doing it, involving functions that return a function of the same type. I hit a roadblock though. I thought to myself, how do I do something so explicitly recursive in definition.

I hit an epiphany. `type node = Char -> node`

Alas, Haskell does not allow for recursion in its type synonyms. So my question is: How do you make types that are inherently recursive like that? What is the type declaration for a function that returns the same kind of function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to wrap the recursive type in a `newtype`.

```
newtype Node = Node (Char -> Node)
```

Comment: Why do you have to say Node before (Char -> Node)?

Comment: @aleeds444 The `Node` before `(Char -> Node)` is the type constructor name. You need to use type constructors when defining new data types.

Comment: @Ankur No, it's the data constructor name. The one after `newtype` is the type constructor.

Comment: When I use :t on the 'Node' in ghci, it says that it is of type (Char -> Node) -> Node. This confuses me. I thought the type would be just Char -> Node. I feel like I do not understand this newtype thing properly.

Comment: @aleeds444 It might help to look at a simpler, non recursive example first. Consider `newtype Example = WrapChar Char`. The type of `WrapChar` is `Char -> Example`. It is a data constructor for the `Example` type, so it returns an `Example` value and since an `Example` value holds a `Char`, it takes a `Char` as its argument. Note that the type can be named the same as the data constructor, but I gave them separate names here for clarity.

Comment: Ooooo, I get it. I thought the constructor and the type had to have the same name. That clears things up. Thank you